# Automatic radio targets from org-mode headlines

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, org-link

Is there a way to have headlines in `org-mode` automatically behave as radio targets? Basically, I am looking for each line starting with `*`  get turned into a radio target.

For example:

```
* My Headline
And this is some text that auto-links to My Headline.
```

which behaves the same as if I had written:

```
* <<<My Headline>>>
And this is some text that auto-links to My Headline.
```

As suggested in the comments, I tried overriding `org-radio-target-regexp` as follows:

```lisp
(defconst org-radio-target-regexp (format "<%s>\\|^\\*\s\\(.+\\)" org-target-regexp)
          "Regular expression matching a radio target.")
```

but this does not seem to do anything... any ideas?